# Memory Issue on IE browser

Tags: javascript

I have one jsp page which contains some Ajax calls. In that Ajax call, I am loading one third party js object. Now when I am keep on using Ajax call, IE continuously increasing it's memory. But when I click on any other link which reload full page or refresh page, IE release all memory usage. It means that Third party js object taking memory on IE only(Working fine on FireFox).

How can I delete that object from browser once it's not in use? I have try

```
delete obj;
```

which not work for me because I don't know the structure of third party js object.
Is there any way to execute only browser refresh functionality without refreshing browser?
Or any other suggestion to resolved this issue?

Thanks in advance.
Navnath

Comment: Here's a good article describing how Javascript uses the `delete` keyword: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: Thanks for link which explains some hidden things behind delete. But my problem still not get solved. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `obj = null`, that may mark it for cleanup.

The other obvious thing to try is `delete window.obj` which should get rid of the whole thing.